# Why can't I insert a NULL value into a column after MySQL Re-installation?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Why can't I insert a NULL value into a column after MySQL Re-installation?

`INSERT INTO table_name () VALUE ()` 
After Re-Installation insert query not working on my local database. But it's working on the same table on my VPS. If I set any default value for that columns its working on a local database, But on VPS no need to set default values .

> version() ~ 10.1.21-MariaDB

Comment: Define "query not working" and paste the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`. Do you have triggers on the table?

Comment: @elenst     additional_resources

CREATE TABLE `additional_resources` (
  `Resources_ID` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Resources_Name` varchar(30) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: Trigger Before Insert 

BEGIN
Declare Next_ID int;
  select IFNULL(max(Resources_ID),0) into Next_ID FROM additional_resources;
  IF Next_ID=0 Then
    set new.Resources_ID=1;
  Else
    set new.Resources_ID=Next_ID+1;
  End IF;
END

Comment: Learn about `AUTO_INCREMENT`, then get rid of the trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MariaDB **10.1.21** or MariaDB **10.2.4**, if you have a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger and columns without default values, and your insert statement is silently ignored, you are most likely affected by the [regression bug](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-11842) which prevents `INSERT`s under certain circumstances.

Previous and later versions should not be affected, the problem was fixed in 10.1.22 and 10.2.5.

*As of today (March 14th, 2017), 10.1.22 goes through final release preparations and can become available any moment now. 10.2.5 will be released later.*

Comment: Thanks a lot . its worked for me after updating 10.1.21-MariaDB to 10.1.22-MariaDB .